# zend db join resultset

Tags: zend-db, inner-join, zend-db-select

I used zend_db_select for joining 3 tables, and in the result set array while I was expecting to see the column names with aliases, it returns an array with keys having no aliases.

```
$dbSelect = $db->select()->from(array("pp"=>"products_photos"),array())
                         ->joinInner(array("ph"=>"photos"), "pp.photo_id=ph.photo_id","ph.photo_id")
                         ->joinInner(array('pr'=>'products'),"pr.product_id=pp.product_id","pr.product_id")
                         ->where("pr.product_id=$row->product_id");

$photoJoinRowSet = $db->fetchAll($dbSelect);
var_dump($photoJoinRowSet);die();
```

RESULT LIKE :

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["product_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["photo_id"]=> string(1) "4" }}
```

While I was expecting :

`array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["pr.product_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["ph.photo_id"]=> string(1) "4" }}`

......i.e with column aliases.

Does anyone know why this happens?? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify any aliases here, so your select will translate to something like `SELECT ph.photo_id, pr.product_id`, without `AS`, which will return `photo_id` and `product_id` as expected.

You need to specify explicitly your aliases if you want the dots in the keys:

```
$dbSelect = $db->select()->from(array("pp"=>"products_photos"),array())
    ->joinInner(array("ph"=>"photos"), "pp.photo_id=ph.photo_id",
      array("ph.photo_id" => "ph.photo_id"))
    ->joinInner(array('pr'=>'products'), "pr.product_id=pp.product_id",
      array("pr.product_id" => "pr.product_id"))
    ->where("pr.product_id=$row->product_id");
```

More information on the  [Zend_Db_Select documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html).

Comment: Thanks. The zend documentation doesn't state this clearly though